# How to run doAsync for an already async call?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have this method that needs to run in the background.

```
override fun doBackground() {
    doAsync {
       val googleClientApi = GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build()

        googleClientApi.connect()
    }
}

override fun onConnected(p0: Bundle?) {
    // Result. 
    dowork()
}
```

How can I leverage **Anko** doAsync so that I don't have to break my code into the call back of `onConnected()`?

Does Anko or Kotlin let me do something like this **pseudocode**:

```
override fun doBackground() {
    doAsync {
        ...
        val connected = googleClientApi.connect()
        continue code execution here instead of on the onConnected()
    }
}
```

Why do I want to do this? Because although I could write the code on the `onConnected()` I do wonder if I can make the code smaller or easier to follow.

Comment: Instead of Anko you should use coroutines. You must write a `suspend fun connect()` and then you can call it inside a `launch` block. What you should _not_ do is run this code on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Anko or Kotlin let me do something like this pseudocode:

No, because method `connect()` of `GoogleApiClient` returns nothing!!

`GoogleApiClient` depends on callback methods which you're achieving by `addConnectionCallbacks()`

**Other Approach**

You can add as an anonymous class in `addConnectionCallbacks` instead of implementing to Class

```
override fun doBackground() {
doAsync {
   val googleClientApi = GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(object : ConnectionCallbacks{
              override fun onConnected(bundle: Bundle?) {

              }

              override fun onConnectionSuspended(value: Int) {
              }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build()

    googleClientApi.connect()
}
}
```

Comment: What benefit would I get from the "anonymous class" besides code being all together? Don't anonymous classes leak?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about making your code shorter and I dought that it will make your code easier to follow either. If you want to execute something after being connected with `GoogleApiClient`, then you need to do that after the api establishes the connection in `onConnected` as you have done already. So if you are trying to write some code just after the `connect` call, and you are expecting this to be frozen at the time when you are calling the `connect` function, then this will cause the ANR in your android application.

However, you can use `runOnUiThread` if you want your `connect` call to run immediately in the main UI thread. You can use the `Runnable` interface as well to keep your code in the same place as you want.